# Linear algebra Coordinate vector of A relative to the basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the coordinate vector relative to the basis $S=(P_1,P_2,P_3)$ of polynomial $P$, where

\begin{align}P&=3-x-2x^2\\[0.3cm]
P_1&=1+x\\
P_2&=1+x^2\\
P_3&=x+x^2\end{align}

I know I must find

$$a(1+x)+b(1+x^2)+c(x+x^2)=3-x-2x^2$$ but I don't know how to continue from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be that \begin{align}a+b&=3\\a+c&=-1\\b+c&=-2\end{align} Do you see why?

---

**Edit:** If you expand your expression, you get $$(a+b)+(a+c)x+(b+c)=3-x-2x^2$$ Now, you may [equate coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equating_coefficients) to obtain the system above.

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: I know the scalars are the coordinates

Comment: @Djhoe Your constant term in $P$ is equal to $3$, yes? But if you multiply out your expression you get that your constant term on the LHS is equal to $a+b$. Repeat for the coefficient of $x$ and $x^2$.

Comment: So a+ax+b+bx^2+cx+cx^2=3-x-2x^2

Comment: @Djhoe Yes, but it is more helpful for you to write it as $$(a+b)+(a+c)x+(b+c)x^2=3-x-2x^2$$ and compare the coefficients "coordinaten-wise" (constant with constat, $x$ with $x$ and $x^2$ with $x^2$).

Comment: hmm but why dont you write it (a+c)x+(a+b)+(b+c)x^2=3-x-2x^2, why do you do it in this specific order?

Comment: ahh now I see thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: from here you will get the System:
$$b+c=-2$$
$$a+c=-1$$
$$a+b=3$$

Comment: How would you solve these system of equations in terms of matrices? Is it gauss elimination or algorithm? I ask because I am confused about what comes after the equal sign and how to solve for that ( I know normal solving...)

Comment: i would use the Gauss Algorithm. Should i do it for you?

Comment: No thanks I got the idea thank you